# Principal Ideals

Tags: field-theory

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity.  I'm trying to prove if every ideal of $R[X]$ is a principal ideal, then $R$ is a field.  So it's sufficient to show $R$ is a division ring.
Question:  What is the connection between principal ideals in $R[X]$ and units in $R$?  Is there a nice natural bridge between the two or am I looking for several steps to get from $a$ to $b$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually quite simple. Suppose $R$ is not a field and let $I$ be a proper nontrivial ideal. Is the ideal $I+\langle X\rangle$ principal?

Comment: I guess I will have to prove to myself first it is an ideal.  is $I + \langle x \rangle$ a commonly known ideal?  I'm not really sure where it came from.

Comment: It's notation for the sum of the ideal $I$ and the principal ideal generated by $X$.

Comment: My apologies....I realize what it represents, it wasn't intuitive for me and maybe it should be.  Is it analogous to the ideal $\{ar + m | r \in R, m \in M\}$ where M is an ideal of $R$ contained in $R - \{a\}$?

Comment: In this case $I$ is not an ideal of $R[X]$, but $\{i+rX:i\in I,r\in R\}$ is, which is what I mean. What you are describing is $\langle a\rangle+M$, and there's usually no need to require that $M$ not contain $a$, so you would only specify that if you want to emphasize it.

Comment: I think parentheses are also often used instead of angle brackets. On an unrelated note, your upvote/accept pushed me over 25k. I didn't realize I was so close. Thanks!